# Display Tuple<int, int> values in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, tuples

I'm struggling with showing `Tuple<int, int>` values in my Razor view.
This `Tuple<int, int>` is inserted in `TempData["SucceededFailed"]` at controller like this:

```
Tuple<int, int> SucceededFailed = new Tuple<int, int>(1, 0);
TempData["SucceededFailed"] = SucceededFailed;
```

I'm looking for the correct syntax, for showing the Tuple in my view, I tried three but all of them throw exceptions.

**View**

```
<tr>
     <td>
          <h3>Result</h3>
          <h4>Succeeded:</h4>
          <h4>Failed:</h4>
     </td>
     <td>
     @if (TempData["SucceededFailed"] != null)
     {
          <h3></h3>
          <h4>@{(Tuple<int, int>)TempData["SucceededFailed"].Item1;}</h4>
          <h4>@{(Tuple<int, int>)TempData["SucceededFailed"].Item2;}</h4>
      }
      </td>
</tr>
```

Code above failes at following line:

```
      <h4>@{(Tuple<int, int>)TempData["SucceededFailed"].Item1;}</h4>
```

**Error**

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

I also tried following:

```
@if (TempData["SucceededFailed"] != null)
{
    <h3></h3>
    <h4>(Tuple<int, int>)@TempData["SucceededFailed"].Item1</h4>
    <h4>(Tuple<int, int>)@TempData["SucceededFailed"].Item2</h4>
}
```

Which failes at:

```
<h4>(Tuple<int, int>)@TempData["SucceededFailed"].Item1</h4>
```

**Error**

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Item1' and no extension
>   method 'Item1' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

At last I tried following code, this was the *only* one, giving me the correct syntax highlighting:

```
@if (TempData["SucceededFailed"] != null)
{
     <h3></h3>
     <h4>@(Tuple<int, int>)@TempData["SucceededFailed"].Item1</h4>
     <h4>@(Tuple<int, int>)@TempData["SucceededFailed"].Item2</h4>
}
```

Which failes at:

```
<h4>@(Tuple<int, int>)@TempData["SucceededFailed"].Item1</h4>
```

**Error**

> 'System.Tuple' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the `TempData` in parenthesis to let the compiler know it's a `Tuple<int, int>`:

```
@(((Tuple<int, int>)TempData["SucceededFailed"]).Item1)
```

Note: The extra parenthesis before `.Item1` and after `@`. This tells the compiler, you want to take the object in `TempData`, cast it to `Tuple<int, int>`, then access the `Item1` property of the result of that cast.

Comment: Very close, I now get: (1, 1).Item1 in my view, so viewing the complete Tuple works, but I would like to get property 'Item1' and 'Item2' shown. I will try this: `<h4>@((Tuple<int, int>)TempData["SucceededFailed"].Item1)</h4>`

Comment: you where very close to an answer, could you modify your answer, with following line, since that one works: `@(((Tuple<int, int>)TempData["SucceededFailed"]).Item1)`, so another extra parenthesis at front and at back, if you modify your answer, then I will accept it, since you helped me out most:)